# Update bones coordinates after apply matrix transformation to SkinnedMesh

Tags: matrix, three.js

I have a problem with skinned meshes and skeletons.
Suppose I have a SkinnedMesh that i want to scale or rotate, but i need to "bake" these transformations on the mesh geometry (using applyMatrix with a matrix composed by scale, translation and quaternion). If i bake these transformations the skeleton of the skinned mesh doesn't updates, and so the bones remains at their initial sizes and coordinates.

I need to bake the transformations so to reset scale to THREE.Vector3(1,1,1) and rotation to THREE.Euler(0,0,0,"XYZ").

If I try to move bones position or scale/rotate them after the transformations bake my SkinnedMesh (obviously) changes.

I took two screenshots to show what I'm meaning.
In the first screenshot (natural scale) you'll see the skinned mesh at it's natural scale, with the skeleton helper displaying correctly. In the second screenshot (bigger scale) i baked a scale transformation, scaling with THREE.Vector3(3,3,3). As you can see the skeleton helper remains to it's initial size.

It is possible to update bones sizes and coordinates without affecting the geometry? Can anybody help me?

Thank you in advance!

Natural scale

[image: natural scale (1,1,1)]

Bigger scale

[image: bigger scale (3,3,3)]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following with success:

```
var p = new THREE.Vector3();
var q = new THREE.Quaternion();
var s = new THREE.Vector3();
mesh.skeleton.findBoneByName("bone-name").matrixWorld.decompose(p, q, s);

//p variable now contains the world position
console.log(p);
```

`mesh` is your `SkinnedMesh` instance. `"bone-name"` is the name of the bone you want to find the world position.